# ejs - include a file from a subfolder file

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

My main template folder is `views`. Inside of that I have another folder called `_layouts` where I have `header.ejs`and `admin_header.ejs`.

so if i have a file inside the `views` folder, say `index.ejs`, I can easily include the files from `_layouts` by doing e.g.

```
<% include _layouts/header %>
```

But now I have made another subfolder inside of the `views` folder called admin, and I have `admin.ejs` in there, but I can't include files from `_layouts` anymore.

I've tried `<% include _layouts/admin_header %>` and `<% include ../_layouts/admin_header %>`

In both cases I get:

```
failed to open views\admin\_layouts\admin_header.ejs
```

is there a way to include files from `_layouts` in a file that is in another subfolder?

Comment: try this  <%- include ("../_layouts/admin_header.ejs" )%>

Comment: I did and i wish I didn't. Can you not post answers that you haven't tested and don't really know?

Comment: I agree i have not tested this incase of your code, but what is the  error you got in this?

Comment: Read the docs [here](http://ejs.co/) your answer is there in `includes`. Also follow the rules [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) being nice takes nothing, especially when you want help @VojislavKovacevic

Comment: @subrahmanyabhat <%- include('../_layouts/admin_header') %> does it

Comment: @Dennington-bear Thanks, I somehow missed it while quickly skimming thru, anyawy didn't mean to come off as rude, I just thought the answer was off the top of his head without really knowing about the subject, but it turns out it was nearly there actually.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to  setting some paths in your route file. Try this, works for me:

```
app.set('views', [path.join(__dirname, 'views'),
                  path.join(__dirname, 'views/your_another_folder/')]);
```

So, inside your template you can call your files, like this:

'<%- include partials/folter/file %>'

Answer (score 0):

this works for me
<%- include("./partials/header.ejs") -%>

'partials' is the subfolder i created inside the views folder

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).